# If a morphism $f:A\to B$ of étale $k$-algebras induces a bijection $\hom_k(B,k_s)\to\hom_k(A,k_s)$, then $f$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be étale $k$-algebras and consider the functor (from the category of étale algebras to the category of finite sets) defined by $F=\hom_k(\_,k_s)$, where $k_s$ is a fixed separable closure of $k$.

If $f:A\to B$ is a morphism which induces a bijection $F(f):F(B)\to F(A)$, I want to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism.

I know that if $A=\prod_i L_i$ is a (finite) product of (finite) separable field extensions, then $\hom_k(A,k_s)$ is in bijection with $\coprod_i \hom_k(L_i,k_s)$ but I don't know how that helps.

(If that helps anyone to search this in the future, this is axiom G6 in order to show that the opposite category of finite étale algebras is Galois.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you know the structure theorem for finite étale $k$-algebras, so you should see that it suffices to prove the claim for the case where $A$ and $B$ are finite separable field extensions of $k$. This is essentially just Galois theory.

Indeed, if $A$ is a finite separable field extension of $k$, then the number of $k$-algebra homomorphisms $A \to k_s$ is equal to the dimension of $A$ as a $k$-vector space. So if $f : A \to B$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism of finite separable field extensions of $k$ such that $F (f)$ is a bijection, then the dimensions of $A$ and $B$ (as $k$-vector spaces) are equal; but $f : A \to B$ is an $k$-linear map with trivial kernel, so it must be an isomorphism.

Comment: Hi @ZhenLin, by the structure theorem you mean that every finite étale algebra is a finite product of finite separable field extensions? If so, yes, I know it.

I thought of basically the same things that you said but I just don't understand why $f$ has trivial kernel in the case of separable field extension and why it suffices to consider this case. I mean, for a general étale algebra, it is not true that $|\hom_k(A,k_s)|$ is the dimension of $A$ as a $k$-vector space.

Comment: It is a general fact that ring homomorphisms between fields are injective. For the case of a general finite étale algebra the reduction you need is that each factor in the domain maps to some factor of the codomain.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is too simple but it is still not clear to me. Why do each factor in the domain maps to some factor of the codomain? It isn't possible that two factors of the domain maps to the same factor in the codomain? It is also not possible to some factor to map to 0?

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens when the codomain only has one factor? Once you understand that case, you can handle the case where there are many factors by splitting into components. This fact about homomorphisms is true for finite products of field extensions in general, by the way.

Comment: Lets say we have a morphism $f:A\to L$. Since $L$ is a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, (a well-known corollary of Zariski's lemma implies that) $\ker f$ is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and then $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is isomorphic to a factor of $A$. Then $f$ factors as $A\to A/\mathfrak{m} \to L$. That is fine. What I don't get in the case of a morphism $A\to B$ is why can't a factor of $A$ map to two factors of $B$ or why can't a factor of $A$ map to $0$. I also don't understand how to conclude our proof.

Comment: @ZhenLin Do I miss something ? I don't think that a factor in the domain maps to some factor in the codomain. Consider the map $k\to k\times k, x\mapsto (x,x)$ which is clearly a ring homolorphism. And actually, if you require that a ring homomorphism preserve 1, a map $L\to \prod L_i$ would never factors through one of the $L_i$.

Comment: @Roland that's what I wanted to say by "why can't a factor of $A$ map to two factors of $B$". Thank you for your example.

Comment: @Roland In general it may happen, but this is where we must use the hypothesis that $F (f)$ is a bijection and the fact that $F (-)$ is not merely a functor into the category of sets but rather a functor into the category of sets with a $\mathrm{Gal}(k_s | k)$-action.

Comment: @ZhenLin actually no, $F$ is just a functor into the category of finite sets here. (As in SGA1 Exposé V.) Could you further explain why $F(f)$ being a bijection implies that $f$ maps one factor of $A$ to one and only one factor of $B$?

Comment: $F$ may be defined as mapping into finite sets but it actually maps into sets with a Galois action. (Just compose each automorphism of $k_s$ with the homomorphisms into $k_s$!) The factors correspond to the orbits. Since $F (f)$ is an equivariant map it must map orbits to orbits; since $F (f)$ is an equivariant _bijection_ the orbits are also in one-to-one correspondence, so the factors are also one-to-one.